# What happed if some one make an object of the action class in another class in struts 2?

Tags: struts2, struts

In our code new freshers had made object of the action classes and used the methods.
How system affected if action class object used throughout the system.

Comment: Could you please provide more details, by editing your question? How is the action class object used, where, maybe share us some of your code.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about an S2 action class.

Turn this question around: since you're (apparently) *not* a "fresher", what do you *think* happens when a class is instantiated? How do you think S2 process a request? (Hint: it instantiates an action class, which is then eventually used to process the request.) How might an instantiated class, given that an S2 action can be a POJO, affect the rest of the system?

All this said:

From an *architectural* standpoint this is a bad idea, because logic used across classes should be properly extracted into a service/utility/etc. class and not tied up with a specific action.

It's also confusing from a cognitive load viewpoint: there's no reason to expect mainline code to manually instantiate an action--actions are instantiated by the framework for the sole purpose of processing requests.

Comment: Additionally for the OP: S2 creates its actions using the ThreadLocal pattern. It depends on how the classes are passed around, if during the course of the request the action were passed into methods this wouldn't be too bad but if the objects were preserved between requests you probably will have (likely unaccounted for) concurrency issues.

Comment: Thanks Dave, we have implemented the service layers instead of making objects. Remove the action class objects.